# Browser seems to show query given by .htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess, url, redirect, mod-rewrite

There seems to be a problem with the approach I'm using to redirect everything to *index.php* which is in my root folder *public_html*. There should be no exceptions This is ofcourse, unless a folder turns RewriteEngine off. For simplicity lets just say I use *www.example.com* as my website.

My .htaccess looks as follows:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?url=$1 [QSA,L]
```

- As an example, let's say in the browser I enter: *www.example.com/test*
- It redirects internally as intended to: *www.example.com/index.php?url=test*

The problem:

- I would like the browser to simply still display: *www.example.com/test*
- However, the browser now displays: *www.example.com/test/?url=test*

This messy name **only shows up if I have a folder named *test*** inside the root directory. If I delete the folder, it shows:

- *www.example.com/test*

Yet, if I add the folder again, it shows:

- *www.example.com/test/?url=test*

It still redirects properly, but it doesn't look clean anymore.
What I'm curious about is what exactly causes it to behave this way and how it can be solved/prevented.

Please, note that I always want to rewrite the url. So I do not want to make exceptions for folders. It should look and work the same no matter if there is a folder or not.

---

edit 1: The root folder would be public_html, so example.com  (as an example)

---

edit 2: Changed phrasing of the question, the question is still the same.

---

edit 3: Changed the formatting of the question.

---

edit 4: Added that I want to rewrite the url, regardless whether there exist or doesn't exist a folder.

Comment: Currently I use as solution to add a trailing slash. So www.example.com/test would first be converted to www.example.com/test/. It doesnt show the /?url=test when using a trailing slash. Yet, I still am unaware to why it showed the url parameter in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use this in your `.htaccess`:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)$ /test/?url=$1 [L]
```

This code will leave you with your desired URL. Make sure you clear your cache before testing it.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, unfortunately it doesn't seem to work. I changed the phrasing and format of the question to be more specific.

Answer (score 0):

This may need further edits to do exactly what you want, but using `RewriteCond` you can specify conditions on when to actually rewrite the url.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
 ##perform rewrite only if requested file does not exist...
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
 ##perform rewrite only if requested directory does not exist...
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)$ /test/?url=$1 [L]
```